# Unusual data types and #include in a header file

Tags: c++, header, ftp

So I'm writing a small FTP interface for a program in Visual Studio 2012 and I'm running into an issue with the header files.  I have my class declaration in FTP.h and it looks like this:

```
// FTP.h
// class declaration for FTPConnection class

#include <WinInet.h>  // <--- Line in question

class FTPConnection{

public:
    FTPConnection(char *serverP, INTERNET_PORT portP, char *usernameP, char *passwordP);
    ~FTPConnection(void);
    bool openConnection(void);
    bool closeConnection(void);
    bool downloadFile(char *webPath, char *localPath);
    bool uploadFile(char *webPath, char *localPath);
    bool status(void);

private:
    HINTERNET internet;
    HINTERNET FTPserver;
    bool connectionStatus;
    char *server;
    INTERNET_PORT port;
    char *password;
};
```

If I leave off the " #include  " line, I get errors about undefined data types and it won't compile.  I don't want to have to include WinInet.h in every file I need to use the class in as that just seems to make things way more complicated than necessary, is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use forward declaration of the types, but you will have to change the `INTERNET_PORT` to a pointer or reference type. You will most likely have to do the same with `HINTERNET`.

Comment: I still don't understand how including WinInet.h will complicate things unnecessary. Can you explain?

Comment: Don't play with plutonium, just include the file.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you are asking.  Is the issue about having to actually put `#include <WinInet.h>` in every file, or that you don't want to have those types pulled in when your ftp file is pulled in? If it's the former, than @trojansdestroy has answered your question, if it is the latter, than your only option is the forward declaration but you are playing with fire in that case as you now have to turn things into pointers or references.

Answer (score 3):

WinInet.h is the header for the [Windows Internet API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That probably includes the data types giving you errors.

If FTP.h includes WinInet.h, simply including FTP.h in another file should be enough (you shouldn't need to include WinInet.h directly).